# How do I use Ruby's new lambda syntax?

Tags: ruby, lambda

Ruby has lambda syntax, so I can use the `->` symbol:

```
a = 0
new  -> { a < 5 }  do
   puts a
   a += 1
end
```

This works very well, but when I try to do this:

```
match "/", to:  -> { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get]
match( "/", to:  -> { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get] )
match( "/", { to:  -> { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get] })
```

all of the return the same syntax error:

```
$ ruby -c -e 'match( "/", to:  -> { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get] )'
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '|'
match( "/", to:  -> { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am mi...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: give the full error stack please.

Comment: ^^^There is no "stack", its an syntax error. however, added line to show the syntax error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that new syntax should be

```
match "/", to:  ->(e) { [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get]
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the syntax should be like this.

```
->(e) { [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing `->` and `lambda` syntax

```
match( "/", to:  lambda { |e| [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get] )
```

And

```
match( "/", to:  -> (e) { [404, {}, ["Hello! I am micro rack app"]] }, via: [:get] )
```

Personally I would use the 'lambda' syntax as it is more rubyish.