# Confused on how to use lambda in ruby for select

Tags: ruby, lambda

I'm working with ruby and I'm just learning lambdas. I have an array of objects and I want to select certain objects from the array based of different conditions like so:

```
result = array.select{|ar| ar.number > 4}
```

I want to put the arguments of the select into a lambda expression i.e. I want to put `|ar| ar.number > 4` into a lambda expression. I've tried a few things including:

```
result = array.select{lambda{|g| g.number > 4}}
```

But this doesn't work.

I've also tried this:

```
l = lambda {g.number > 4}
result = array.select{|g| l}
```

and that also doesn't work. Also I need to pass my lambda express to a function so I don't think the first way I did it would have worked. How would I do this?

Comment: As the two answers show you, the part you were missing was specifying the argument to the block for use in its contents.

Answer (score 19):

`Enumerable#select` takes a block, not a lambda. So, you need to pass it a block.

Thankfully, there is an operator which will convert a lambda or proc (and in fact anything which responds to `to_proc`) to a block: the unary prefix `&` operator, which is only valid in argument lists (where it converts a proc to a block) and in parameter lists (where it converts a block to a proc).

So, if you have a lambda `l`, you can pass it as a block to method `foo` like so:

```
foo(&l)
```

Your second problem is that your lambda doesn't take any arguments, but the block passed to `select` takes one argument, so you need to create your lambda with one argument:

```
l = lambda {|el| el.number > 4 }

# I prefer this syntax, though:
l = -> el { el.number > 4 }
```

Putting all that together, we have:

```
result = array.select(&l)
```

Answer (score 6):

To pass a lambda (or a proc) to a method as a block, you have to use the special `&syntax`:

```
result = array.select &mylambda
```

Also, your lambda (or proc) must specify the name for parameters it will receive and use. Thus:

```
l = lambda { |g| g.number > 4}
result = array.select &l
```

Answer (score 5):

A clean way to do this is to use Ruby's ["stabby" lambda syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632585/how-do-i-use-rubys-new-lambda-syntax):

```
l = ->(ar) { ar.number > 4 }
result = array.select(&l)
```

The more "traditional" way to define a `lambda` is as such:

```
l = lambda { |ar| ar.number > 4 }
result = array.select(&l)
```

Note that you don't strictly need to use a `lambda`; you could also use a `proc`*:

```
p = proc { |ar| ar.number > 4 }
result = array.select(&p)
```

* The [main difference between proc and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740046/whats-the-difference-between-a-proc-and-a-lambda-in-ruby) is that `lambda` will throw an error when passed too few or too many arguments, while `proc` will ignore it. Another [subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new) is that the `return` statement inside a `proc` will cause execution to return *both* from the closure *and the enclosing method* (if any).

Comment: "Proc" rhymes with "block" and "lambda" is greek, just like "method". Argument binding and `return` in a lambda behave like in a method and in a proc behave like in a block.